# conversion from 'QTableWidgetItem* const' to 'QChar' ..or QString...is ambiguous

Tags: c++, qt, type-conversion, qstring

I am studying qt - and in the book C++ GUI Programming With Qt 4 I am trying to get all code to work. I am having problems with converting a selection of the contents from a custom table widget into plain text.

existing code in the book:

```
void MyTableWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) {
        int distance = (event->pos() - startPos).manhattanLength();
        if (distance >= QApplication::startDragDistance())
            performDrag();
    }
    QTableWidget::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}
void MyTableWidget::performDrag()
{
    QString plainText = selectionAsPlainText();
    if (plainText.isEmpty())
        return;

    QMimeData *mimeData = new QMimeData;
    mimeData->setText(plainText);
    mimeData->setHtml(toHtml(plainText));
    mimeData->setData("text/csv", toCsv(plainText).toUtf8());

    QDrag *drag = new QDrag(this);
    drag->setMimeData(mimeData);
    if (drag->exec(Qt::CopyAction | Qt::MoveAction) == Qt::MoveAction)
        deleteSelection();
}
```

I am trying to write selectionAsPlainText() and deleteSelection().

```
QTableWidgetSelectionRange MyTableWidget::selectedRange() const
{
    QList<QTableWidgetSelectionRange> ranges = selectedRanges();
    if (ranges.isEmpty())
        return QTableWidgetSelectionRange();
    return ranges.first();
}

QString MyTableWidget::selectionAsPlainText()
{
    QTableWidgetSelectionRange range = selectedRange();
    QList<QTableWidgetItem *> items = selectedItems();
    QString str;

   for (int i=0;i<range.rowCount();i++){
       for (int j=0;j<range.columnCount();j++){


// error on this line
               str+=QString(items.at(i*(range.columnCount()-1)+j)->data(Qt::DisplayRole)));


           if (j!= range.columnCount()-1)
                str += "\t";
       }
       str += "\n";
    }
    return str;
}
```

In this try, out of many, I am attempting to place the items from the `QTableWidgetItem` in a `QString`, separated either by `"\t"` or `"\n"`.

I am unable to try any type of such action because I am getting errors in trying to place any content into the QString.

Everything I have tried so far gives me an error like

```
conversion from 'QTableWidgetItem* const' to 'QChar' is ambiguous
 or
error: no matching function for call to 'QString::QString(QVariant)'
```

I don't know how to make this type conversion, I have not seen examples on how to specify type casting... Though as I understand it, selecting the Qt::DisplayRole of the data, I should implicitly have a QString...

How can I make this type conversion work ?

I included more code to suggest that the TableWidget is likely of an unknown type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with, heavily nested parentheses are difficult to read.  I would recommend splitting the offending line into several lines.  Secondly, the type returned from `QTableWidgetItem::data` is a `QVariant`, which can be converted to a `QString` using the `QVariant::toString()` member function.  Also, I don't think `i*(range.columnCount()-1)` is quite what you want.

Given this, your code should look something like the following:

```
int index = i*range.columnCount()+j;
QTableWidgetItem* item = items.at(index);
str += item->data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
```